# Baby Rudin Theorem $9.5$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, linear-independence

This is the definition which we need in the proof of our theorem:
[image]

This is the theorem which we need in the proof of our theorem:

[image]

There is the theorem $9.5$:

A linear operator $A$ on a finite-dimensional vector space $X$ is one-to-one if and only if the range of $A$  is all of $X$.

There is the proof:

Let {$x_1,...,x_n$} be a basis of $X$. The linearity of $A$ shows that its range $\mathfrak R(A)$ is the span of the set $Q = {Ax_1,...,Ax_n}$. We therefore infer from Theorem $9.3(a)$ that $\mathfrak(A) = X$ if and only if $Q$ is independent.
We have to prove that this happens if and only if $A$ is one-to-one.

Suppose $A$ is one-to-one and $\sum_{}c_i Ax_i = 0 $. Then $A(\sum_{}c_i x_i)  = 0 $, hence $\sum_{} c_i x_i = 0 $, hence $c_1 = ... = c_n = 0$, and we conclude that $Q$ is independent.

Conversely, suppose $Q$ is independent and $A(\sum_{}c_i x_i) = 0$. Then $\sum_{}c_iAx_i = 0$, hence $c_1 = ... = c_n = 0$, and we conclude: $Ax = 0$ only if $x$ $=$ $0$. If now $Ax = Ay$, then $A(x-y)$ $=$ $Ax - Ay = 0 $, so that $x - y$ $=$ $0$, and this says that $A$ is one-to-one.

In the last part of theorem, I don't understand how do we conclude that $Ax = 0$ only if $x = 0$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's the definition of linear independence, which was assumed.

Comment: @CyclotomicField how does the independence of $Q$ imply that $Ax = 0$ if $x = $ ?

Comment: definition implies $c_1=...=c_n=0$. And $0\cdot\vec v = \vec 0$ as well as $\vec 0 + \vec 0 =\vec 0$

Comment: @BigCoconut Can you please explain it more explicitly? how does $c_1 = ... = c_n = 0$ imply that $Ax = 0$ only if $x = 0$ ? I'll confirm your answer.

Comment: @JohnNash, Do you see that $c_1=...=c_n=0$ implies $c_1e_1+...+c_ne_n=0?$

Comment: @JohnNash what definition are using for a linearly independent set ? Typically it's that all linear combinations of the vectors will only be zero when all the coefficients are zero.

Comment: @BigCoconut Yes I see it. But how does it imply the result?

Comment: @BigCoconut $ 0 \cdot \vec{v} = \vec{0} $ doesn't imply that $\vec{v} = 0 $

Comment: @JustinYoung  What if $\text{im } A \subset \ker A$?

Comment: JohnNash, the point is not that $Ax=0$ if $x=0$, but rather it’s the converse. Every $x$ can be written as $x=\sum c_ix_i$ for some $c_i$; if $Ax=0$, then $\sum c_i Ax_i = 0$ and so, by the linear independence of $Q$, all $c_i=0$, which means that $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$Ax = A(\sum_{}c_i x_i)... \implies c_i = 0 \implies x = \sum_{}c_i x_i = 0$